# Get unique data from while sql query (multiple rows)

Tags: php, sql, tags, cloud, smarty

How do I get only unique result from this code? I just try query with 
SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement and don't work it :(

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include_once ('/var/www/video/configs/db.php'); 

$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY VIDEOID ASC LIMIT 0,10");
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $tags = $row['tags']; }

$rand = rand(5, 55);
$list  = explode(',', $tags);
foreach ($list as $link) { 
$tags = array( array('tag' => "$link", 'num' =>  $rand, 'link' => "$link"), ); 

$array = array_unique($tags); print_r($array);

}
?>
```

Just need to implement this on my web site

http://www.xarg.org/2008/08/tag-cloud-plugin-for-smarty/

Comment: 1. **Do not** suppress errors using `@` 2. Add error handlers 3. Stop using `mysql_` functions; they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: please could you explain more what exactly you want and please paste the Table schema

Comment: 4. Define *and don't work it*.. what didn't work? 5. understand what your code is doing, I see overwriting of `$tags`

Answer (score 1):

To get unique `tags` from the database, you have to build your query correctly.
Suggestion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM videos ORDER BY videoid ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This should return unique `tags`.

Also, understanding what your code is doing is key when programming. The following is not what you want to do:

```
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $tags = $row['tags']; }
```

This is grabbing each row and overwriting `$tags` each time, which means you will ONLY have the last tag grabbed. You want to build an array of tags:

```
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $tags[] = $row['tags']; }
```

This is saying to add a new array item each time. You do the same thing in your `foreach` statement by overwriting `$tags`.

Then you can make your code neater by removing the un-needed quotes in

```
$tags = array( array('tag' => "$link", 'num' =>  $rand, 'link' => "$link"), );
                              ^     ^                             ^     ^
```

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, don't forget to accept. If you have persisting issues with this subject, feel free to post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get unique `tags`, try this query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM videos ORDER BY VIDEOID ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you need to be DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyColumnName FROM videos ORDER BY VIDEOID ASC LIMIT 0,10
```